# How to find contiguous areas in matrix with less memory?

Tags: algorithm, memory, graph, language-agnostic, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix of 0 and 1. Now I would like to count all contiguous areas in the matrix that contain only 1.

```
allocate a new matrix "visited" to track visited elements
COUNT = 0
for each element E in the matrix
  if E == 1 and E is not visited
    COUNT = COUNT + 1
    run BFS/DFS to visit all not-visited matrix elements connected to E
return COUNT
```

If the matrix is N x N then we need additional N x N "visited" matrix and also a queue/stack for BFS/DFS. Now I wonder if there is an algorithm, which solves this problem and requires less memory.

Comment: The wiki article on flood fill http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill can give you some useful hints

Comment: If you don't need to preserve the original matrix, you could zero out elements in the original matrix instead of using visited, so you only need the queue/stack.

If you do want to preserve the original matrix but (a) you can modify it in the meantime and (b) it's stored in a format that allows more than just 0 or 1 (in theory, you only need one bit per element for a binary matrix, but in practice you're likely to be using a byte per element anyway), you could temporarily set visited elements to -1. Then treat -1 like 0 in the search, and when you're done restore it.

Comment: I guess this is obvious, but if you are allowed to change the matrix you can track visited elements by zeroing them out or if there are spare bits in the matrix elements, use bit 0 for data and bit 1 for the 'visited' flag.  Hard to get rid of the stack, however.

Comment: in C, you can try this to save Space: int visited[ceil((N*N)/64)]; -then use bit operations to store\read flags -this will require 1Bit per Cell, N^2/8 Bytes -ex: 64x64 ~ 512Bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory is so critical, then you can use the following approach:

Additionally keep only an array with the length of matrix's one row, then scan matrix rows from up to bottom, and each time when you process current row, there are intervals of continuous 1's in it, which can merge different pieces located above them, for example

```
1110001110011
1111001110011
0011111000011
```

if you consider only first 2 rows, there are three different pieces, but 3rd row merges first two of them. So you can use the additional array to keep what different pieces are there until last row, i.e. initially it will be filled with 0's, and when you are just starting scanning 3rd row of matrix, that array should look like 1111002220033, i.e. each number shows to which part that cell belongs. After processing 3rd row they will be merged and additional array will become 0011111000033. So after scanning each row some parts are merged, and some parts disappear. Each time a part disappears, you can increment the counter to have the answer in the end.

However, this is more tricky and complex approach than BFS/DFS, and I don't think that you will need to use this anyway in practice.